# Trying to understand Threading, when being swamped by events

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, events

Currently I am writing a program that using my kinect sensor.

I am very much new to using vb.net.

I have read many different posts regarding threading, but they usually involve a button click event. This in one event when the user presses a button on the form which would set in motion a new thread to do some routines so it won't freeze up the main UI.

However when it comes to the Kinect Sensor, and say for instance, the Skeleton Stream, it constantly updates thirty frames a second.  I feel as though I am being swamped by events.

When I attempt to slow things down by using a "Thread.Sleep" function, my UI obviously locks up. I am trying to start a new thread to handle an action during a particular gesture, but I am unsure weather I can use some of the threading examples I have read about or how to implement them in the code when the event fires at thirty frames a second.

Here is my code from within the "SkeltonFrameReady" event Subroutine, it is the "sendkeys" portion I would like to thread separately, and have the main UI update the position of the persons hand.

Perhaps I need the entire Subroutine on a separate thread? But I would need the labels that show the relevant position of the persons hand to update in real time, the "Thread.Sleep" stops this from happening.

Thanks you to whom ever has some ideas about handling this.

```
Public Sub SensorSkeletonFrameReady(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs)

    Dim skeletons(-1) As Skeleton
    Dim passiveCount As Integer = 0
    Dim activeCount As Integer = 0

    Using skeletonFrame As SkeletonFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame()
        If skeletonFrame IsNot Nothing Then
            skeletons = New Skeleton(skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength - 1) {}
            skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(skeletons)

        End If
    End Using

    If skeletons.Length <> 0 Then
        For Each skel As Skeleton In skeletons

            '// Count the Number of People in the room up to six
            If (skel.TrackingState = SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked) Then
                activeCount = (activeCount + 1)
            ElseIf (skel.TrackingState = SkeletonTrackingState.PositionOnly) Then
                passiveCount = (passiveCount + 1)
            End If
            numPeople = (activeCount + passiveCount)
            Dim People As String = numPeople.ToString
            HowManyPeople.Text = "Number of People: " & People

            ''// Focus on the closest Person
            Dim closestID As Integer = 0
            If Not Me.kinect.SkeletonStream.AppChoosesSkeletons Then
                Me.kinect.SkeletonStream.AppChoosesSkeletons = True
                ' Ensure AppChoosesSkeletons is set
            End If
            ' Start with a far enough distance
            Dim closestDistance As Single = 10000.0!

            If (skel.Position.Z < closestDistance) Then
                closestID = skel.TrackingId
                closestDistance = skel.Position.Z
            End If

            If (closestID > 0) Then
                ' Track this skeleton

                Me.kinect.SkeletonStream.ChooseSkeletons(closestID)


                '//Swipe Right and Left
                If ((skel.Joints(JointType.HandRight).Position.Z < skel.Joints(JointType.ElbowRight).Position.Z) _
                    AndAlso (skel.Joints(JointType.HandLeft).Position.Y < skel.Joints(JointType.ElbowLeft).Position.Y)) Then
                    ' //right hand below head height 
                    If ((skel.Joints(JointType.HandRight).Position.Y < skel.Joints(JointType.Head).Position.Y) _
                        AndAlso (skel.Joints(JointType.HandRight).Position.Y > skel.Joints(JointType.ShoulderRight).Position.Y)) Then
                        ' //right hand right of left shoulder
                        If (skel.Joints(JointType.HandRight).Position.X > skel.Joints(JointType.ShoulderLeft).Position.X) Then

                            Dim XPosition = skel.Joints(JointType.HandRight).Position.X - skel.Joints(JointType.ShoulderRight).Position.X
                            CurrentHandPositionX.Text = "Horizontal-Position: " & XPosition.ToString
                            If XPosition > OldPosition Then
                                OldPosition = XPosition
                                KinectGesture.Text = "Swipe Right"


                                ''//I would like this to be on a separte thread
                                Dim WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
                                WshShell.SendKeys("{Right}")
                                Thread.Sleep(220)

                            ElseIf XPosition < OldPosition Then
                                OldPosition = XPosition
                                KinectGesture.Text = "Swipe Left"

                                ''//I would like this to be on a separte thread as well
                                Dim WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
                                WshShell.SendKeys("{Left}")
                                Thread.Sleep(220)

                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If



                '//Selection "Press"
                If ((skel.Joints(JointType.HandRight).Position.Z < skel.Joints(JointType.ElbowRight).Position.Z) _
                       AndAlso (skel.Joints(JointType.HandLeft).Position.Y < skel.Joints(JointType.ElbowLeft).Position.Y)) Then
                    '//right hand below head height 
                    If ((skel.Joints(JointType.HandRight).Position.Y < skel.Joints(JointType.Head).Position.Y) _
                        AndAlso (skel.Joints(JointType.HandRight).Position.Y > skel.Joints(JointType.ShoulderRight).Position.Y)) Then
                        '//right hand right of left shoulder
                        If (skel.Joints(JointType.HandRight).Position.X > skel.Joints(JointType.ShoulderLeft).Position.X) Then

                            Dim ZPosition = skel.Joints(JointType.ShoulderCenter).Position.Z - skel.Joints(JointType.HandRight).Position.Z
                            CurrentHandPositionZ.Text = "Depth-Position: " & ZPosition.ToString
                        End If
                    End If
                End If




                '//Fast Scroll Right
                If ((skel.Joints(JointType.HandRight).Position.Z < skel.Joints(JointType.ElbowRight).Position.Z) _
                AndAlso (skel.Joints(JointType.HandLeft).Position.Y > skel.Joints(JointType.ShoulderLeft).Position.Y) _
                AndAlso (skel.Joints(JointType.HandLeft).Position.Y < skel.Joints(JointType.Head).Position.Y)) Then
                    ' //right hand below head height 
                    If ((skel.Joints(JointType.HandRight).Position.Y < skel.Joints(JointType.Head).Position.Y) _
                        AndAlso (skel.Joints(JointType.HandRight).Position.Y > skel.Joints(JointType.ShoulderRight).Position.Y)) Then
                        ' //right hand right of left shoulder
                        If (skel.Joints(JointType.HandRight).Position.X > skel.Joints(JointType.ShoulderRight).Position.X) Then
                            KinectGesture.Text = "Fast Scroll Right"
                            Dim WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
                            WshShell.SendKeys("{Right}")
                        End If
                    End If
                End If

            End If
        Next

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

"it is the "sendkeys" portion I would like to thread separately"

Instead of:

```
Dim WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys("{Right}")
```

You can directly use [SendKeys.Send()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx), which is built into VB.Net for you:

```
SendKeys.Send("{Right}")
```

As to the threading part, is it your goal to limit the arrow keys by placing a delay in-between them?  If yes, you could use a standard Timer() from the ToolBox that simply gets turned on/off.  You could setup a boolean value to indicate whether the arrows should still be sent and then check that in the Tick() event to know when to turn the timer back off.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response. So, the actual Sendkeys.Send would be in the tick event? or would it be a condition that "If the timer is started, return"?

Comment: I think I get it, the condition is "If the Timer is started then do nothing, if the timer is not started use Sendkeys". Then I could set the intervals in the tick event. They could even be dynamic to be set on the main form. Thank you so much for the insight. I believe I am able to do this.

Comment: Right, I was thinking SendKeys.Send() in the Tick() event.  You would have to code in there somehow to detect when to turn the Timer back off though.  If you need to send the arrow, and Timer.Enabled is already True, then you'd just leave it on and another arrow will be sent when it Tick()s again.

Comment: Also, you could use the **same** Timer() for both Arrows, and simply change a variable to indicate which direction should be sent.

Comment: Well I got this working. There is a phenomenon happening now, that I didn't think wouldm. Before I was able to slow down the thread with a Thread.Sleep Function, and the kinect sensor tracked my hand back and forth in real time. However now, when I use the timer, the kinect waits for my gesture to finish before it moves the arrow in either direction. Interesting. I may try some different technics with the timer and see some different out comes. Thank you again.

Comment: If your Timer() Interval is pretty low then the main UI thread would have to deal with it as well as the constant stream of kinect events.  I would have thought that the opposite, putting Sleep() in the event handler would have slowed it down more than the Timer approach.

Comment: Another approach would be to set a DateTime variable to a point in the future (DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds()), when the next arrow key should be fired off.  Then, when an event comes in, you only actually send the keystroke and update the DateTime again if the current time is PAST the last stored "key event" in the DateTime value.  This needs no Timer() and no Sleep().  It relies on the Kinect raising events constantly enough to act like a Timer.